# How can I capture sound from WebView on my Cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio, audio-recording

I'm writing a Cocoa application which has a WebView. (Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion)

I need your help for recording sound/audio from a web page shown in WebView.

I would like to record the audio to the file, which is from the WebView when it shows a web page that generates sound.

Is there any simple way to do that? I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Thanks.